# Convert csv to different csv

Tags: python, csv

I need to convert my csv:

Original:

```
"DSP";"Fecha";"Moneda_a_pagar_a_medio";"Impresiones";"Importe_a_pagar_a_medio";"eCPM"
DSP;01/12/2017;USD;2.324;596,73;0,65
```

What I´m looking for:

```
DSP,Fecha,Moneda_a_pagar_a_medio,Impresiones,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,eCPM
DSP,01/12/2017,USD,2324,596.73,0.65
```

Code:

```
import csv
with open('test.csv', 'rb') as csvfile:
    spamreader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    print spamreader
```

Answer (score 2):

Using Pandas, change `f` to `'test.csv'` to read from file:

```
import pandas as pd

data = '''\
"DSP";"Fecha";"Moneda_a_pagar_a_medio";"Impresiones";"Importe_a_pagar_a_medio";"eCPM"
DSP;01/12/2017;USD;2.324;596,73;0,65'''
f = pd.compat.StringIO(data)

df = pd.read_csv(f, sep=";", thousands='.', decimal=',')
df.to_csv('output.csv', index=False)
```

output:

```
DSP,Fecha,Moneda_a_pagar_a_medio,Impresiones,Importe_a_pagar_a_medio,eCPM
DSP,01/12/2017,USD,2324,596.73,0.65
```

Comment: That's better.  +1  Anton vBR and andrew_reece

Comment: `<_csv.reader object at 0x07C01FB0>` I have this results on my CSV

Comment: Martin, are you saying you get that result when you use the code in this answer exactly?  That looks like you are using the `csv` module.

Comment: I´m using CSV module because I have the data on a csv

Comment: Pandas reads CSVs directly, this answer doesn't require the `csv` module.

Comment: could you edit you answer with the exactly code please? I can't understand it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/162056/discussion-between-andrew-reece-and-martin-bouhier).

Answer (score 0):

```
import csv

with open('org.csv', 'r', newline='') as f:
    spamreader = csv.reader(f, delimiter=';', quotechar='|')
    data = list(spamreader)

with open('new.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',', quotechar='|')
    writer.writerows(data)
```